# PHP 7.2.8 build с openssl на Debian

Tags: php, linux, debian

Не могу собрать php 7.2.8 с openssl

which openssl - /usr/bin/openssl

и делаю ./configure --with-openssl

пробовал ./configure --with-openssl-dir=/usr/bin/openssl не помогло

OpenSSL: disabled (install ext/openssl)

поставил libssl и скомпилировал с --with-openssl-dir=/usr/lib/ssl не помогло

Comment: вы указываете на бинарник, а вам скорее всего нужен пакет openssl-dev (точнее, одна из реализаций) с заголовочными файлами

Comment: @etki apt-get не находит

Comment: Попробуйте libssl-dev. Судя по всему, некоторые штуки поменялись с тех пор, как я их в последний раз трогал

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо доустановить еще 2 пакета:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config
```

- libcurl4-openssl-dev - файлы и документация для разработки libcurl
- pkg-config - управление флагами компилятора и компоновщика для библиотек

один только libcurl4-openssl-dev не поможет) ([тут](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.debian.php) описано что нужно в User Contributed Notes)